# not getting the desired result in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

Why I am not getting the list sizes of list1 and list2 as 1000
in the code below:

https://pastebin.com/ttcbkjqR

My main method code is as below:

```
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

    for(int j=0; j<2; j++) {
        executor.submit(new Worker(j));
    }

    executor.shutdown();
    System.out.println("All tasks submitted: ");

    try {
        executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {

    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Time taken: " + (end - start));
    System.out.println("List1: " + list1.size() + "; List2: " + list2.size());
```

And here the `Worker` class:

```
class Worker implements Runnable{
    private int id;
    
    public Worker(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    private Random random = new Random();
    private final Object lock1 = new Object();
    private final Object lock2 = new Object();

    public void stageOne() {
        synchronized(lock1) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            WorkerThreadPool.list1.add(random.nextInt(100));
        }
    }

    public void stageTwo() {
        synchronized(lock2) {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            WorkerThreadPool.list2.add(random.nextInt(100));
        }
    }

    public void process() {
        for(int i=0; i<500; i++) {
            stageOne();
            stageTwo();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting thread: " + id);
        process();     
        System.out.println("Completed: " + id);   
    }
}
```

on one time running I am getting

```
List1: 986; List2: 989
```

Other time I am getting

```
List1: 994; List2: 981
```

But each time It should give

```
List1: 1000; List2: 1000
```

What's wrong here?

Comment: click on the pastebin link..unable to post whole code here..

Comment: Maybe it's because ArrayList is not thread safe

Comment: But I am invoking it inside synchronised block..so it does not matter..may be a different reason?

Comment: It must be thread safety because if I do this `List<Integer> list1 = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())` and same with list2 then its always 1000. Try it yourself, don't take my word for it :) If I'd know exactly why then I'd formulate it as an answer

Comment: I expect it's something to do with you using two locks.

Comment: well, `Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>())` will give correct answer ..but that's not the issue..I am not able to figure out why despite making two methods thread safe using two locks-lock1 and lock2, I am not getting correct answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```java
 class Worker implements Runnable{
    
        private int id;
        
        public Worker(int id) {
            this.id = id;
        }
    
        private Random random = new Random();

        private final Object lock1 = new Object();
        private final Object lock2 = new Object();

       .....
```

The result is unpredictable because threads are not sharing lock.

Here, `lock1` and `lock2` serve no purpose.

This reason is: When you submit tasks in `WorkerThreadPool` using `executor.submit(new Worker(j));`, each thread gets its own copy of `locks` (each `Worker` instance creates new `lock1` and `lock2`).

Here's updated `Worker` with *sharedLock* logic:

```java
class Worker implements Runnable {

    private int id;
    Object sharedLock;

    public Worker(int id, Object sharedLock) {
        this.id = id;
        this.sharedLock = sharedLock;
    }

    private Random random = new Random();

    public void stageOne() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        synchronized (sharedLock) {
            WorkerThreadPool.list1.add(random.nextInt(100));
        }
    }

    public void stageTwo() {

        try {
            Thread.sleep(1);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        synchronized (sharedLock) {
            WorkerThreadPool.list2.add(random.nextInt(100));
        }
    }

    public void process() {
        for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
            stageOne();
            stageTwo();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Starting thread: " + id);
        process();
        System.out.println("Completed: " + id);
    }

}
```

Updated `WorkerThreadPool`:

```java
public class WorkerThreadPool {

    public static List<Integer> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    public static List<Integer> list2 = new ArrayList<>();

    static Object sharedLock = new Object(); // share lock

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);

        for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++) {
            executor.submit(new Worker(j, sharedLock)); // pass same lock to each instance of Worker
        }

        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println("All tasks submitted: ");

        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {

        }
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

        System.out.println("Time taken: " + (end - start));
        System.out.println("List1: " + list1.size() + "; List2: " + list2.size());
    }

}
```

**Output:**

```java
All tasks submitted: 
Starting thread: 1
Starting thread: 0
Completed: 0
Completed: 1
Time taken: 1842
List1: 1000; List2: 1000
```